# Which query performs better in MongoDB ($or or $facet)?

Tags: query-performance, index, mongodb

I have a query similar to the following;

```
    db.getCollection('list').aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "events":[{
                $match: {
                   'type': 'Event'
                }
            }],
            "tasks": [{
                $match: {
                   'type': 'Task'
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    {$project: {activity:{$setUnion:['$events','$tasks']}}},
    {$unwind: '$activity'},
    {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$activity" }}
]);
```

One another easier approach to write this query is by using $or operator.

```
    db.getCollection('list').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [{
            type: 'Event'
        }, {
            type: 'Task'
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/cthurston/7aead8229e10caa0be175babf7e8ddf1

The query that I'm working with is very similar, except I have other fields, not just 'type' going through this example. My idea is that, if I use **$facet** I'd get better performance if I create correct indexes for each query (that is inside $facet). On the other hand, if I use $or query as it is in the example, **Mongo** may struggle while trying to find the correct index for the query. Is this how it works?

**Edit**: It seems MongoDB can handle indexes for $or statements;

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$facet - Index Use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#index-use) says:

> The $facet stage, and its sub-pipelines, cannot make use of indexes,
> even if its sub-pipelines use $match or if $facet is the first stage
> in the pipeline. *The $facet stage will always perform a COLLSCAN
> during execution*.

[$or Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes) says:

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either
> performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by
> indexes, MongoDB performs index scans.

And, your query's `$match` stage:

```
$match: {
    $or: [
        { type: 'Event' }, 
        { type: 'Task' }
    ]
  }
```

can be simply written as:

```
$match: { type: { $in: [ 'Event', 'Task' ] } }
```

See [$or versus $in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in) says:

> When using $or with  that are equality checks for the
> value of the same field, use the $in operator instead of the $or
> operator.

Using the `$or` with proper indexing is likely to perform better than that of using the `$facet` stage.